# craeate grid of buttons independent from resolution of device

Tags: android, button, resolution, dpi

I want to create a grid of `Buttons` in my android app. The problem is, when I test this on low resolution devices, some `Buttons` are displayed off the screen. How can I fix that?

This is the layout I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/b0"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/b4"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/b5"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/b6"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/b7"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/b8"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/b9"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/b10"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/b11"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/b12"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/b13"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/b14"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/b15"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="  Taget:-" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tar"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="  Current:-" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cur"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="  TimeLeft:-" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tim"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="" />


</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Is your problem solved or do you need further assistance? Please don't forget to accept the answer which helped you most!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a `GridLayout` you need to specify where exactly you want the `Views` to be positioned and how big they are supposed to be. Try something like this:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2" />

    ...

</GridLayout>
```

To define how many rows and columns there are use these two attributes on the GridLayout:

- `android:columnCount`
- `android:rowCount`

You can define the position of a View inside the GridLayout with these two attributes:

- `android:layout_column`
- `android:layout_row`

And you can define how many rows or columns a View spans with these two attributes:

- `android:layout_rowSpan`
- `android:layout_columnSpan`

Please note that the GridLayout was only added with API level 14! If you want to use the GridLayout in earlier versions you need to use the GridLayout from the support library:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    ...    

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

---

Also note that you **ARE NOT** supposed to hardcode a fixed size for each `Button`. Set height  and width to `wrap_content`, the `GridLayout` will take care of setting the size of the `Buttons`.

You can decrease the amount of columns you display by using a resource selector:

For example define this in **res/values/dimens.xml** so smaller devices use only two columns:

```
<dimen name="column_count">2</dimen>
```

And in **res/values-w350dp/dimens.xml** you define the same dimen resource with a bigger value:

```
<dimen name="column_count">3</dimen>
```

The **w350dp** means that all device which have a width bigger than 350dp use 3 columns instead of the default 2.

To make this work you of course need to set this dimen resource as the `columnCount` on your `GridLayout`:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="@dimen/column_count"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    ...

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: thank you sir, that helps me a lot. But the problem here is, I want to make this grid independent from screen size of the device. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that? Do you mean you always want the grid to be as big as the screen is?

Comment: Yes. looks same in every device.

Comment: If you want the `GridLayout` to be as big as the screen you need to set `match_parent` as width and height of the `GridLayout` like I do in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, the Android developer's page on [supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) is a pretty comprehensive guide on this subject.

In short, you're on the right track using dp instead of straight pixels, as Android will scale most things on its own pretty well.  However, this system is not always perfect in practice.  One way to get around this is to create different layouts for different screen sizes.

> By default, Android resizes your application layout to fit the current device screen. In most cases, this works fine. In other cases, your UI might not look as good and might need adjustments for different screen sizes. For example, on a larger screen, you might want to adjust the position and size of some elements to take advantage of the additional screen space, or on a smaller screen, you might need to adjust sizes so that everything can fit on the screen.
>
> The configuration qualifiers you can use to provide size-specific resources are small, normal, large, and xlarge. For example, layouts for an extra large screen should go in layout-xlarge/.

For example, you could use a similar layout with only 3 columns instead of 4 for small-medium screens (if that would work with your game), or make the size of each button smaller.

Additionally, you could declare in your application that small screen sizes are not supported.  This is pretty universally frowned upon if you can avoid it, since it does exclude some users from your app.